# Creating portable Git repository for XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, git, repository, portability

I would like to start working on an XCode iOS project on my iMac and then, in few days, move it into my MacBook Air and **continue working from there whilst keeping and accessing to the source code version of the initial repository** (the one started on the iMac).

Is this possible? And if so is there any tutorial/guide I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

Use a remote git server, like Github or Bitbucket.
Here you find all the info you need
https://help.github.com